# Cannot detect your screen, graphics and devices. Display unclaimed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display

I am really new to the Linux world. My system is running really slow since after installing Ubuntu 14.04. It is showing some type of error:

```
The system is running in low graphics mode.
Cannot detect your screen, graphics and devices.
```

I am running the OS in low graphics mode and I have to go to boot options every time I switch on my PC and select the low graphics mode option in Advanced options for Ubuntu → Recovery mode.

How can I get my system working normally?

`sudo lshw -c display`

```
*-display UNCLAIMED
description: VGA compatible controller
product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: d
bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
version: a2
width: 64 bits
clock: 66MHz
capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:dff40000-dff5ffff
```

Comment: Open terminal Ctrl+Alt+t, then run `sudo lshw -c display`. Add its output to the question (BTW, use that small [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/481381/edit) under the question)

Comment: jasser@Jasser:~$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
description: VGA compatible controller
product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: d
bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
version: a2
width: 64 bits
clock: 66MHz
capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:dff40000-dff5ffff                 These are the results @Sneester and it shows the display unclaimed. Sorry for not posting the question properly

Answer (score 0):

Install the accelerated nVidia Graphics driver `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```